# Sum and combine keys from dictionary in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible fact like (it might have many hypervisors):

```
"combined_data": {
    "hypervisor-01": [
        {
            "disk": 150,
            "id": "okd-service-01"
        },
        {
            "disk": 25,
            "id": "okd-master-02"
        },
        {
            "disk": 25,
            "id": "okd-master-01"
        }
    ],
    "hypervisor-02": [
        {
            "disk": 20,
            "id": "okd-bootstrap-01"
        },
        {
            "disk": 30,
            "id": "okd-worker-01"
        },
        {
            "disk": 25,
            "id": "okd-master-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I need to create another fact with the data summarized as:

```
"result": [
    "hypervisor-01": 200,
    "hypervisor-02": 75
]
```

I tried with map and combine but didn't get anything working so far.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary might be more convenient. For example,

```yaml
  cd_keys: "{{ combined_data.keys()|list }}"
  cd_vals: "{{ combined_data.values()|map('sum', attribute='disk')|list }}"
  result: "{{ dict(cd_keys|zip(cd_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
    hypervisor-01: 200
    hypervisor-02: 75
```

Optionally, you can use *json_query*. The below declaration gives the same result

```yaml
  cd_query2: '[].[key, sum(value[].disk)]'
  result: "{{ dict(combined_data|dict2items|json_query(cd_query2)) }}"
```

Use [community.general.dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries) if you want to get a list. For example,

```yaml
  cd_query3: '[].[[key, sum(value[].disk)]]'                                                
  result: "{{ combined_data|dict2items|json_query(cd_query3)|                              
              map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - hypervisor-01: 200
  - hypervisor-02: 75
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    combined_data:
      hypervisor-01:
        - {disk: 150, id: okd-service-01}
        - {disk: 25, id: okd-master-02}
        - {disk: 25, id: okd-master-01}
      hypervisor-02:
        - {disk: 20, id: okd-bootstrap-01}
        - {disk: 30, id: okd-worker-01}
        - {disk: 25, id: okd-master-03}

    cd_keys: "{{ combined_data.keys()|list }}"
    cd_vals: "{{ combined_data.values()|map('sum', attribute='disk')|list }}"
    result1: "{{ dict(cd_keys|zip(cd_vals)) }}"

    cd_query2: '[].[key, sum(value[].disk)]'
    result2: "{{ dict(combined_data|dict2items|json_query(cd_query2)) }}"

    cd_query3: '[].[[key, sum(value[].disk)]]'
    result3: "{{ combined_data|dict2items|json_query(cd_query3)|
                 map('community.general.dict') }}"

  tasks:

     - debug:
         var: result1
     - debug:
         var: result2
     - debug:
         var: result3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people are interested, the following set_fact will do the trick:

```
- set_fact:
    data_sum: "{{ data_sum|default([]) + [{item: my_attribute}] }}"
  vars:
    my_attribute: "{{ kubeinit_validations_libvirt_combined_disk_usage[item] | map(attribute='disk') | list | sum }}"
  with_items: "{{ kubeinit_validations_libvirt_combined_disk_usage.keys() | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it which can be used via a task/play/group var and doesn't involve using a slow task loop:

```
{%- set result = [] %}
{%- for host, hostdata in combined_data.items() %}
{%- set _ = result.append({host: hostdata | json_query('sum([*].disk)')}) %}
{%- endfor %}
{{- result }}
```

It's useful to use of jmespath to select and sum the disk values because it will also ensure that if the values don't exist, it won't error out.